# Time & Date dependent Page Content

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a video feed to only display on Thursdays between 7PM and 8PM because that's when the live feed is playing. For reasons I'll not go into, I'm not allowed to have it up at any other time. Since I'm new to JavaScript I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but from what I've been able to learn this is what I've got.

```
var hour = getHours()
var day = getDay()

document.onload=function timechange() {

if day==4 && hour>19 && hour<21
    document.getElementById(livefeed).innerHTML =
        "Text one"

    else
        document.getElementById(livefeed).innerHTML = 

            "Text two"


}
```

This is example text obviously but the majority of the content will change on the page. Do I have to add some sort of function in my HTML page to make this work?

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: And also, how are getHours() and getDay() defined?

Comment: To answer yor first question, I wasn't getting any error, it's just that nothing was happening. As for your second question, I have no idea what I'm doing really because I'm brand spanking new to JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the simple version, that's almost that. getDay() and getHours() are defined on the Date class:

```
function shouldShowVideo() {
    var currentDate = new Date(),
        currentDay = currentDate.getDay(),
        currentHour = currentDate.getHours();

    return (currentDay == 4 && currentHour > 19 && currentHour < 20);
}

if (shouldShowVideo()) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

There is one big problem with this approach though. Because you do it in JS, the video will be loaded on your page, no matter what (so people could potentially get the link to it).
Also, because you are executing your JS after the onload event fired, there could be a few seconds where the video will be displayed. What you can do to improve this is run this code on DOM Ready event instead (here is the jQuery helper: http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Your best option would still be to move this logic on the server. That way, you don't have to worry about all this: no JS involved.

Comment: Hey bud! Thanks so much for your answer. In order to avoid the video being loaded, the natural state of the page would be set so that the video is not displayed. It only gets added into the document upon the condition, rather than being _removed_ from the document if the condition is not present. Thanks for the help @Adrien! And also, since I'm now using Joomla, I'll be able to better control the publishing instead of having to hand code it ;)